# Qt installed on Mac but not in /usr/include

Tags: qt, qt5, osx-yosemite, eclipse-cdt, libraries

I have installed QT5 by the QT Installer from the official website and QT4 with command line $ apt-get install qt4-mac. Both have been successful but I can't find qt on /usr/include/. I have QT5 installed for sure, since I have QT creator and I can run some examples.

Here is a screenshot of my QT Preference.
http://postimg.org/image/vaus93ect/
http://postimg.org/image/q5tdc4rhn/

I searched but everybody who had installed QT have found it in /usr/include.

Thanks

PS : I work on Mac OS Yosemite. And unfortunately I am trying to make it work with Eclipse CDT but since I don't find libraries in /usr/include I can't get it work

Comment: A [symlink](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-creating-symbolic-link-ln-command/) might help.

Comment: Are you sure you installed Qt using apt-get on Mac OS ? AFAIK apt-get is a linux only aptitude frontend

Comment: Oups I used macports $ port install qt4-mac and not apt-get. But I installed it by the QT Installer too so

Comment: @Melebius you mean I have to create /usr/include/qt manually with the command $ ln ?

Comment: @Amin I would try it. And don’t forget to check permissions of the target files.

Comment: @Melebius that still strange after all QT Installer should do it by himself am I right ?

Answer (score 0):

`/usr/include` belongs to the operating system. Nothing that you ever manually install should touch that location, unless it comes from Apple.

You've got Spotlight, simply press ⌘-Space, type Creator, wait for it to find it, press ⌘-Enter or ⌘-Click on the result and a Finder window will open up, showing you where the Qt Designer's bundle is. That's likely where the rest of it will be. It's OS X, things are supposed to be easy :)